# SSH:could not resolve hostname **.**.***.** in windows OpenSSH while giving commands

Tags: ssh, putty, vnc, tunnel

My basic idea is to secure my VNC connection using Secure shell.

For this I am using OpenSSH for windows.

I have installed SSHD on server.

And PuTTY and SSH on client which gives me 2 options for client use.

Case 1:

When I try to connect using 'PuTTY' ,where I have enabled tunneling option for security, I am successfully able to log into the server and then I start my vnc session and it also runs smoothly.

But my problem is this VNC session is not communicating through the tunnel which I expected. And according to this https://websistent.com/how-to-use-putty-to-create-a-ssh-tunnel/ ; it should go through the selected tunnel and I could see the same by selecting the traffic through the port.

Case 2:

When i try 'SSH' client to connect, i am again able to successfully log into the SSHD server.

But when i try giving available commands such as ssh w21821@10.31.128.34 - l ,ssh - w w21821[:10.31.128.34]

I get SSH :Could not resolve host name : name or service not known

I am unable to find why i am failing to establish this tunnel using both the options.

Any guidance would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Could you re-check those command examples? All the punctuation looks a bit messed up.

Comment: @grawity : Thanks for your reply. These are the available commands : ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
     [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
     [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
     [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
     [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
     [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
     [user@]hostname [command]able commands

Comment: @grawity : and i am unable to access any of them